# match names between vectors and assign corresponding values

Tags: r

This is a problem about efficiency in R. I have two numerical vectors with `names` attributes, and I want to efficiently assign the values of one vector to the other based on the common `names`.

For example, the first vector is defined as:

```
set.seed(1);
a<-rep(NA,10);
names(a)<-1:10;
d<-a;  #  we will need this later 
a

 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

and the second vector is defined as:

```
b<-sample(letters, 5);
names(b)<-sample(1:10, 5);
b

9  10   6   5   1 
"g" "j" "n" "u" "e"
```

now the following code does exactly what I want, it looks for all `names(b)` that are common with `names(a)` and assigns to those places in `a` the values of `b`:

```
for(p in 1:length(b)){
    a[which(names(a) == names(b)[p])]<-b[p]
};

a

1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
"e"  NA  NA  NA "u" "n"  NA  NA "g" "j"
```

My question is: **is there a better more efficient way of doing this**? I am dealing with much larger vectors and I keep thinking that there must be a better way of doing this.

A more sophisticated method like:

```
d[which(names(d) %in% names(b))]<- b
d

1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
"g"  NA  NA  NA "j" "n"  NA  NA "u" "e"  

all.equal(a,d)

[1] "4 string mismatches"
```

produces wrong results because it requires that `names(b)` and `names(a)` are ordered first, which also does not seem to be an optimal strategy.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `which` is not necessary in your second solution. `d[names(d)%in% names(b)]<-b` works.

Comment: hmm, for me it does not. It gives me the identical result shown above when `which()` is included. Notice that it is different than the `a` after the for-loop.

Comment: If both are named, then, `a[names(b)] <- b` is sufficient.

Comment: @Arun thanks! This is an even better solution!

Comment: See joran's answer when `b` is not a subset of `a` as user1609452 notes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a[intersect(names(b), names(a))] <- b[intersect(names(b), names(a))]
> a
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
"e"  NA  NA  NA "u" "n"  NA  NA "g" "j"
```

Comment: `a[names(b)] <- b` should be sufficient.

Comment: That will work as long as `names(b)` is a subset of `names(a)`.

Comment: Yes, in that case, you just need to subset over the original length of "a".

Answer (score 3):

CORRECT ANSWER:

Based on a comment from @flodel

```
a[match(names(b), names(a))] <- b
```

OLD ANSWER:

This gets close. It does not preserve the names of `a`. I am not sure why. You could reassign the names of `a` after the fact.

```
a <- b[match(names(a),names(b))]
```

Comment: I would worry that b's names may not be a subset of a's.

Comment: @user1609452 Good point. I still think the match function is worth mentioning. I do like the idea of using intersect though - I had not thought of that for my own coding.

Comment: @user1609452. It should not be a concern, since `match` will return `NA` and `a[NA] <- ...` has no effect on `a`. Now this is just my guess, but I think this approach will be more efficient (faster) than using `intersect` as I guess that assigning at specified indices is faster than using names.

Comment: @user1609452. Thanks. I had tested with `length(b) == 1`. With a longer `b` containing one or more `NA`, it still does not throw an error but it does have a destructive effect on `a`. See `a <- setNames(c(0, 0), c("A", "B"))` and `b <- setNames(c(1, 2), c("A", "Z"))` for example. Learnt something today!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a[names(a) %in% names(b)] <- b[names(a[names(a) %in% names(b)])]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just do this:

```
a[names(b)] <- b
> a
#   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
# "e"  NA  NA  NA "u" "n"  NA  NA "g" "j"
```

---

If `b` is not a subset of `a`, for example:

```
set.seed(45)
a <- rep(NA, 10)
names(a) <- sample(10)
#  7  3  2  9 10  8  1  5  4  6 
# NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 

b <- sample(letters, 5)
names(b) <- sample(1:15, 5)
#   7  14   2   5   3 
# "j" "w" "h" "k" "z" 

len <- length(a)
a[names(b)] <- b
a[1:len]
#   7   3   2   9  10   8   1   5   4   6 
# "j" "z" "h"  NA  NA  NA  NA "k"  NA  NA
```

Comment: What if the vector names weren't in numeric order?

Answer (score 0):

1 liner for you:

```
a[as.integer(names(b))]<-b
```